# Is this set not simply connected?

Tags: complex-analysis

As an example of a set that is not simply connected the lecturer gave us this picture: of a set that is not simply connected:

[image]

Have I misunderstood something? It looks simply connected to me. I mean we have the two points $P_1,P_2$, and two curves between them. Can't one curve be continuously transformed into the other curve?

Comment: There is a hole in the domain. And $P_1$, $P_2$ are on the boundary.

Comment: @orangeskid No, sorry it is not, those are the curves I mean, it isn't a hole. If you look at them as curves, is it simply connected then?

Comment: Oh, then it is simply connected.

Comment: @orangeskid thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the region *enclosed by* the wiggly curve, then it is simply connected.  But if you mean the set consisting of the wiggly curve itself, that is *not* simply connected, and your argument with $P_1$ and $P_2$ doesn't count because they are not elements of the set.

Or consider: a circle is *not* simply connected.  But the region enclosed by the circle (that is, a disc) is simply connected.